# Как в pygame отразит изображение по горизонтали, вращать и менять прозрачность

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Как в pygame отразить изображение по горизонтали, вращать и менять прозрачность.

Надо еще сделать атлас и как мне из одной картинки выборочно выбирать то что мне нужно.

И чтобы я не задавала такие глупые вопросы пожалуйста киньте в меня руководством или еще чем нибудь.

P.S. я немного глупенькая и не научилась еще гуглить нужную информацию    (^◕ᴥ◕^)

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению могу помочь только с отражением и вращением.

Отражение выполняется с помощью команды `pygame.transform.flip(surface, xbool, ybool)`, где surface - поверхность для отражения, xbool определяет, нужно ли горизонтальное отражение (True, если да), ybool определяет необходимость вертикального отражения.

Поворот - команда `pygame.transform.rotate(surface, angle)`, где surface - поверхность, а angle - угол поворота.

Руководство по pygame вот: https://www.pygame.org/docs. Сразу скажу, оно на английском.

Надеюсь я вам помог. Да пребудет с Вами сила ;)